# I am trying to make these chemical molecules into a nice table

Tags: tables, graphics, tabularx, chemfig

I am writing a organic chemistry report and would like to create a nice table with these two molecules with captions A and B to fit into a lab report

**ehtyl acetate**

[image]

**toluene**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}        
\resizebox{4cm}{2cm} {
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ethylAcetate.png} &
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{toluene.png} \\
{\Large\textbf{(A)}} & {\Large\textbf{(B)}} \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

If you run it, you'll see that toluene is much larger than ethyl acetate, and the captions are too small. I would greatly appreciate any pointer. Thank you!

Comment: The graphics are told to have a width equal to `\textwidth`. Since toluene is thinner, it has to stretch more to fill the width. Why not explicitly set the widths to be different?

Comment: Do you need `\resizebox`? It produces an awkward aspect ratio and squeezes your table in a way you may not want. If your aim is to have the chamical formulae side by side with captions (A) and (B), maybe it's better to take a look at the [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) packages.

Comment: First, try using the natural sizes.  Resizebox will take care of fitting it on the page.

Comment: You have added the [tag:chemfig] tag – does that mean you want to use that package for the molecules? Do you want to place the molecule's names below them? Or do you actually have a figure where those two are subfigures with separate captions?